# How to convert pdf to an open text format in a fast way?

Tags: pdf, text

How to convert pdf to an open text format in a fast way? i got hundreds of pdfs from my old hd and i'd like to clean them and convert to a safe open format, so i've been scatering internet allover and the only thing i found was an program called pdftotext but i'd like to know if is there any other faster ways, can anyone help me?

Comment: What exactly about `pdftotext` is too slow, and what do you hope to improve by a different program? Note that you'll loose the formatting, and lots of files will need editing. There's NO total safe way to convert PDFs to good text. I'd recommend keeping the PDFs.

Comment: You can use `abiword` which has the `--to=doc` flag as in. `for pdf in ./some/path/*.pdf; do abiword --to=doc "$pdf"; done`. This will create a `.doc` file but keep your original `.pdf` files in tact.

Comment: Try the various solutions and time them on your machine.